# How can I iterate through a Celery Chain in Django?

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm using Celery 5.1.0 with Django 3.2.3 and have a Celery Chain set up. I wish to run this chain in a loop, but I need to ensure that the loop only starts again once the previous set of commands in the chain have completed.

This is the Chain:

```python
def base_data_chain(user_email, store):


    chain = (
            product_count.s(store=store) |
            get_data.s(store=store) |
            normalise.s() |
            merge.s() |
            send_task_email.s(user_email=user_email, store=store))
                             
    chain()
```

What I need is somthing like this:

```python
for store in stores:
    base_data_chain(user_email=user_email, store=store)
```

But I need the loop for each `store` not to begin until the previous `store` has been processed.

Any help on the best way of achieving this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this (with some off-line help) by iterating through all the tasks and adding them to a single chain - i.e.

```py
from celery import chain

def stores_data_chain(user_email, stores):
    store_chain = chain()
    for store in stores:
        store_chain |= product_count.s(store)
        store_chain |= get_data.s(store=store)
        store_chain |= normalise.s()
        store_chain |= merge.s()
        store_chain |= send_task_email.s(user_email=user_email, store=store)
    return store_chain()
```

The only gotcha to watch out for is that each task receives the output from the previous task.

In the example above his means that the `product_count` function receives the store_id on the first loop (correct) but on the second loop it receives the both the next store_id (correct) and the return from send_task_email (not required).

To get around this I had to refactor the `product_count` function to accept args rather than kwargs and then discount the first argument (if there is more than one).

Hope this answer is helpful to others facing a similar issue.